# Retrieve one class model data and use in another class model Django

Tags: python, django

I want to retrieve data of one model class, make it a list of tuples and put as a choices in other model class. Two classes have not any kind of relationship.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

def get_categories_list(restaurant):
    clist = list(Category.objects.filter(restaurant=restaurant))
    categories = []
    for i in range(len(clist)):
        name = clist[i].name
        slug = clist[i].slug
        tup = tuple([slug,name])
        categories.append(tup)
    return categories

class Product(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CATEGORIES = get_categories_list(restaurant)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, choices=CATEGORIES)
```

here is some classes from models.py module

Comment: Why not just make a `ForeignKey` to `Category`, since then you can retrieve the `restaurant` with `product.category.restaurant`.

Comment: You mean no need for restaurant = foreignkey in product class?

Comment: I is my first ever project in Django

Comment: Yes It work in case of shell. But in other cases it occurs error. I am changed my model classes relationship as you suggessted. I cannot to show restaurant fields in my product admin page. I tried many ways. Could you help me?